# Error when trying to run node-sass via npm

Tags: javascript, npm, sass, node-sass

I am trying to run node-sass via npm.

Here is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css/ --recursive"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

It installs correctly, but when I try and run the command "npm run sass", I receive the error below:

"An output directory must be specified when compiling a directory"

My folder structure:
package.json
package-lock.json
scss (folder)
dist (folder) > css (folder)
node_modules (folder)

This script used to work fine some time ago on other projects, but now is not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue. I changed the script to

```js
"sass": "node-sass -w scss/ -o dist/css"
```

and it worked. I re-added --recursive and all worked as intended (same script as in original question). I'm not sure where I went wrong exactly, but glad it's fixed.